# When I create an asp.net project in visual studio community 2017 no .csproj file is created

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I create an asp.net project in visual studio community 2017 only .sln file is created, no .csproj file, is it not suppose to create .csproj file also?

Comment: It is and does. Did you select an empty solution instead of an ASP.NET Project perhaps? What did you actually do?

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen. If it *did* happen, reinstall VS.

Comment: I actually created asp.net 'web site' not 'web project'. I presume .csproj does not get created in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a `.csproj` file you have to create a "Web Project" and not a "Website". Website project is use to create `.ASPX` files in Web pages application compiled on the fly.